Scala 3: Nonexhaustive match for Vector, but not for Seq
Using Scala 3.4.2:
Vector(1, 2, 3) match
  case Vector()  => println("empty")
  case _ :+ last => println(s"last: $last")

gives me an (in my opinion incorrect) nonexhaustiveness warning
[warn] -- [E029] Pattern Match Exhaustivity Warning: ...
[warn] 5 |  Vector(1, 2, 3) match
[warn]   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[warn]   |match may not be exhaustive.
[warn]   |
[warn]   |It would fail on pattern case: Vector(_, _*), Vector(_, _*), Vector(_, _*), Vector(_, _*), Vector(_, _*), Vector(_, _*)

If I use Seq instead of Vector, the code compiles fine.
It looks like this is the same thing for Scala 3 that has been discussed for Scala 2 in the bug https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/12240.
Also, it might relate to https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/12252 which is marked "fixed in Scala 3".
My questions are:

Is this an actual bug in Scala 3?
If yes, is it already known / documented somewhere, or should I create a new bug ticket?


See this other question asked today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78720251/get-compiler-to-notice-exhaustive-match-on-vector - If it doesn't complain with Seq then that is either a bug or a weird special handling of the compiler just for Seq. IMHO, special casing the compiler is not a good idea, either the language get a proper feature to define custom exhaustive checks otherwise any pattern match on something that is not an ADT should be considered non-exhaustive and a possible source of bugs.

There is no special casing: Vector is a sealed trait so the compiler tries to prove that a match is exhaustive, Seq is just a trait so an exhaustivity check is not performed at all (because the compiler does NOT check for exhaustiveness in every case, just in those where it can be proven at all).

To expand on the above: in the 2.13 spec you can read that only sealed are guaranteed to be checked for exhaustive pattern matching. More checks can be enabled with flags but are not enabled by default.

Regarding the bug, it is about verifying the exhaustiveness of unapplySeq (so that compiler could verify that vararg matching could exhaust remaining cases). :+ does not rely on unapplySeq (as far as the compiler is concerned), it's a different case.


Since there is no Scala 3 specification released yet (AFAIK it is still in development), I'll use Scala 2.13 spec (2.13 spec + list of changes in Reference is the closest approximation of a Scala 3 specification that we currently have):

If the selector of a pattern match is an instance of a sealed class, the compilation of pattern matching can emit warnings which diagnose that a given set of patterns is not exhaustive, i.e. that there is a possibility of a MatchError being raised at run-time.

There is only a mention about sealed when mentioning exhaustive checks. For anything else, the behavior is not defined by the spec, so at best it's implementation-specific.
Scala 2.13.4 release notes mentions -Xlint:strict-unsealed-patmat flag which may add more exhaustive checks.

There is a chance you have it enabled somewhere, e.g. if you do -Xlint with all options, or if you have something like sbt-tpolecat, which enables a lot of flags


Vector is a sealed trait (on 2.13, and so on Scala 3 since it uses 2.13's standard library)

Seq is just trait

bugs you mentioned are about exhaustive checks of unapplySeq, so basically things like:
Vector(1, 2, 3) match
  case Vector()  => println("empty")
  case Vector(multiple*) => println(s"last: ${multiple.last}")

while +: was mentioned there as something that should be anylyzed by the compiler, it was more of a wish - it is NOT implemented and I expected it will never be because it's just an arbitrary
object :+ {
  def unapply[A, CC[_] <: Seq[_], C <: SeqOps[A, CC, C]](t: C with SeqOps[A, CC, C]): Option[(A, C)] = ...
}

There is no way for the compiler to guess what this does internally and how it relates to other matches. Someone would have to adds a special case in the compiler... which could not be added for any other user-provided unapply so I don't expect it to happen.


Putting it all together:

when you are using Seq compiler does not try to check for exhaustiveness by default (with some -X flag it might)
when you are using Vector it's a sealed so it will try to prove an exhaustive check
improvements to the compiler allow to prove exhaustive check when one uses unapplySeq (case Vector(...) =>)
neither +: nor :+ are Vector.unapplySeq so the improvements above does not concern them, and they are not exhausting any possibilities as far as the compiler is concerned.
what you observe most likely works as intended (after all there is no Scala 3 specification, so we cannot be certain without asking developers), it's unlikely a bug, even if it does not work as you'd hope it should.

